# Display specific content of each tab of a single page

Tags: html

I have a page composed of 4 tabs.
I want to switch from one tab to another and display its specific content.
As you can see in the following snippet, I want to see "1" when I click on the Tab1, "2" when I click on the Tab2 and so on.
How could I do to make it work ?
Thank you very much for your help.

```
<div>
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#1">Tab1</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#2">Tab2</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#3">Tab3</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#4">Tab4</a>
</nav>


  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="1">1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2">2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="3">3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: research `JavaScript` and go from there

Comment: You may have to use javascript/jquery. And use the click event. You need to hide the other panel and show the one you click at. 
Refer to jquery 
https://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/hide/